# Model name not translated to chinese

Tags: django, django-models

I am going to translate django models from English to Chinese.
I have translated the App Name to chinese, but model name not working

```
class DiseaseType(models.Model):
    diseasetype = models.CharField(_('diseasetype'), max_length=DEFAULT_LENGTH,blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('disease type')
        verbose_name_plural = _('disease types')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.diseasetype)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DiseaseType Model, change the Meta like this:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = '疾病类型'
    verbose_name_plural = '疾病类型'
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass `_('diseasetype')` to the `models.CharField` constructor.  Actually, I don't know how that does not fail as the constructor is supposed to enforce you to use keyword arguments only.

Also, could you please post more details of the translation files you are using and you process to generate and compile them? This will sure shed some more light.